# Scala Functional Literals with Implicits

Tags: function, scala, literals, implicit, currying

Forgive me if this has already been asked elsewhere.  I have a Scala syntax question involving function-values and implicit parameters.

I'm comfortable using implicits with Scala's currying feature.  For instance if I had a sum function and wanted to make the second argument an implicit:

```
scala> def sum(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) = a + b
sum: (a: Int)(implicit b: Int)Int
```

Is there a way to do this using the function-value syntax?  Ignoring the implicit for a moment, I typically write curried function-values like this:

```
scala> val sum2 = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int) => (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

However, the function signature in the second approach is much different (the currying is being expressed explicitly).  Just adding the implicit keyword to b doesn't make much sense and the compiler complains as well:

```
scala> val sum2 = (a: Int) => (implicit b: Int) => a + b
<console>:1: error: '=>' expected but ')' found.
       val sum2 = (a: Int) => (implicit b: Int) => a + b
                                              ^
```

Furthermore partially-applying sum from the very first approach to get a function-value causes problems as well:

```
scala> val sumFunction = sum _
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: Int
       val sumFunction = sum _
                         ^
```

This leads me to believe that functions that have implicit parameters must have said parameters determined when the function-value is created, not when the function-value is applied later on.  Is this really the case?  Can you ever use an implicit parameter with a function-value?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you, but I do have a clarifying question: in your second paragraph you talk about a `sum` *function* but your corresponding code example shows a `sum` *method*. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Hi Jörg - My understanding is that a method is merely a function that is associated with a class or object.  All of the functions above were typed into the Scala REPL; no user-defined classes or objects were created. So I'd say we're only dealing with functions here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
scala>  val sum2 = (a: Int) => {implicit b: Int => a + b}
sum2: (Int) => (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

This will just make b an implicit value for the scope of the function body, so you can call methods that expect an implicit Int.

I don't think you can have implicit arguments for functions since then it is unclear what the function is. Is it `Int => Int` or `() => Int`?

The closest I found is:

```
scala> case class Foo(implicit b: Int) extends (Int => Int) {def apply(a: Int) = a + b}
defined class Foo

scala> implicit val b = 3
b: Int = 3

scala> Foo()
res22: Foo = <function1>

scala> res22(2)
res23: Int = 5
```

Answer (score 9):

In this snippet

```
scala> val sum2 = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int) => (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

Note that the precise type of `sum2` is `Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]]`. It could also be written as

```
val sum2 = new Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]] {
    def apply(a: Int) = new Function1[Int, Int] {
        def apply(b: Int) = a + b
    }
}
```

Now, if you try to make `b` implicit, you get this:

```
scala>     val sum2 = new Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]] {
     |         def apply(a: Int) = new Function1[Int, Int] {
     |             def apply(implicit b: Int) = a + b
     |         }
     |     }
<console>:8: error: object creation impossible, since method apply in trait Function1 of type (v1: Int)Int is not defined
               def apply(a: Int) = new Function1[Int, Int] {
                                       ^
```

Or, in other words, `Function`'s interfaces do not have implicit parameters, so anything with an implicit parameter is not a `Function`.

Answer (score 5):

Try overloading the apply method.

```
scala> val sum = new Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]] {
         |      def apply(a: Int) = (b: Int) => a + b
         |      def apply(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) = a + b
         |}
sum: java.lang.Object with (Int) => (Int) => Int{def apply(a:Int)(implicit b: Int): Int} = <function1>

scala> sum(2)(3)
res0: Int = 5

scala> implicit val b = 10
b: Int = 10

scala> sum(2)
res1: Int = 12
```