# What does the keyword 'implicit' mean when it's placed in front of lambda expression parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have seen this kind of code many times before, most recently at scala-user mailing list:

```
context(GUI) { implicit ec =>
  // some code
}
```

`context` is defined as:

```
def context[T](ec: ExecutionContext)(block: ExecutionContext => T): Unit = { 
  ec execute { 
    block(ec) 
  } 
}
```

What purpose does the keeyword `implicit` achieve when placed in front of a lambda expression parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Scala Functional Literals with Implicits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326132/scala-functional-literals-with-implicits)

Comment: For posterity, additional detailed explanation: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/implicit-parameters.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
scala> trait Conn
defined trait Conn

scala> def ping(implicit c: Conn) = true
ping: (implicit c: Conn)Boolean

scala> def withConn[A](f: Conn => A): A = { val c = new Conn{}; f(c); /*cleanup*/ }
withConn: [A](f: Conn => A)A

scala> withConn[Boolean]( c => ping(c) )
res0: Boolean = true

scala> withConn[Boolean]{ c => implicit val c1 = c; ping }
res1: Boolean = true

scala> withConn[Boolean]( implicit c => ping )
res2: Boolean = true
```

The last line is essentially a shorthand for the second last.

Comment: BTW, rather than using implicit parameters to propagate the context (in this example, `Conn`) through the computation, you can use the Reader monad. https://gist.github.com/1395578

Comment: Thanks for the gist too. Starred it.

Comment: def withConn[A](f: Conn => A): A = { val c = new Conn{}; f(c); /*cleanup*/ this is missing an ending }   :)