# No implicit view available for partially applied method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

So I have the following method that wraps a `Seq`-like object in an `Option`.

```scala
def noneIfEmpty[S <% Seq[_]](seq: S): Option[S] = {
  if (seq.isEmpty) None else Some(seq)
}
```

I'd like to be able to use this method to transform the results of computations wrapped in a `Try`. Say I do this with a `List[Int]`:

```scala
scala> val tryList = Try(List(1,2,3))
tryList: scala.util.Try[List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2, 3))
```

I should be able to use `noneIfEmpty` to map the `Try[List[Int]]` to a `Try[Option[List[Int]]]`. This works fine if I use an anonymous function and explicitly pass the list to `noneIfEmpty`...

```scala
scala> tryList map (list => noneIfEmpty(list))
res1: scala.util.Try[Option[List[Int]]] = Success(Some(List(1, 2, 3)))
```

...but it breaks if I try to pass `noneIfEmpty` as a partially applied function.

```scala
scala> tryList map noneIfEmpty _
<console>:40: error: No implicit view available from S => Seq[_].
              tryList map noneIfEmpty _
                          ^
```

It also works fine if I narrow `noneIfEmpty` to only accept lists:

```scala
scala> def noneIfEmptyList[A](list: List[A]): Option[List[A]] = noneIfEmpty(list)
noneIfEmptyList: [A](list: List[A])Option[List[A]]
```

```scala
scala> tryList map noneIfEmptyList _
res2: scala.util.Try[Option[List[Int]]] = Success(Some(List(1, 2, 3)))
```

What's going on here? Is there some kind of type erasure voodoo at work or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that a view bound is syntactic sugar for an implicit parameter, so your method is really

```
def noneIfEmpty[S](seq: S)(implicit ev: S => Seq[_]): Option[S]
```

Unfortunately you cannot partially apply a method that takes implicit parameters, as the process of eta-expansion (i.e. converting a method to a function) requires implicits to be resolved in advance.

Ultimately your problem reduces to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414172/partially-applying-a-function-that-has-an-implicit-parameter).